# Database design for generics

Tags: sql, database, generics, database-design

I'm wondering what is the best method to store generic classes in a database. For an easy illustration assume the following classes:

```
Interface IShape
  Center: Point
  Size: Point
  Color: Int

Class Line : IShape
  (IShape Members...)
  LineWidth: Int
  Orientation: Int

Class Circle: IShape
  (IShape Members...)
  Fill: Bool
  FillColor: Int

Class Drawing
  Name: String
  Elements: List<IShape>
```

I see the following options:

1. Storing all objects in one table which has the columns of all possible IShape objects. Then after getting the lines from the database, check for the type and create an object of the specific class.
   This will cause an "messy table", no clear seperation between types.
2. Storing the IShape members in one table and the other fields in corresponding tables. Get the IShape elements and check which fields need to be loaded additionally for each object. 
   This will cause a lot of database traffic.
3. Like No.2 but instead of loading each element and look which fields need to be loaded, do one query per type which returns the joined elements with the correct fields.
   This will also cause more database traffic(or at least queries) than No.1 and also may need resorting.

How would you recommend storing them in the database? Is there some best practice? Interestingly I couldn't find any recommendation.

Comment: Which platform are you using? Oracle has Object storage (which internally works like Option 1), Postgresql has table inheritance ...

Comment: I want to use MS-SQL and maybe firebird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic `List<IShape>` is something of a red herring here since it is nothing more than the representation of a one-to-many link, or perhaps a slice of a many-to-many link table; there is no uniquely generics-related mapping complexity in your question.

There is really no single best practice here due to the depth of the [object-relational impedance mismatch](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ObjectRelationalImpedanceMismatch).  There are 3 well-established techniques for mapping inheritance hierarchies, and none of them can fully represent the constraints correctly.

1. **Table per type**, your option 2, with 1-to-1 primary key references between subtype and base-type tables.  To express mutually exclusive subtypes requires some denormalization (including a discriminant column as part of the primary key, and incorporating a CHECK constraint on it in each subtype table), potentially large number of joins per query, but strongest referential integrity overall.
2. **Table per hierarchy**, sometimes called a "parking lot" table, your option 1 using a column to discriminate object type.  Very messy due to large numbers of uninitialized columns, questionable referential integrity due to inability to express a reference to a subtype, but column applicability can be enforced by CHECK constraints.
3. **Table per concrete type**, which you didn't mention: let `Line` and `Circle` be tables, and let `IShape` be a view of the union of the common columns of the two tables.  Questionable referential integrity due to inability to express a reference to a base type, but keeps the number of joins down without introducing nullable columns.

To obtain the best fidelity in referential integrity you'd need some variation on the discriminated table-per-type construction, perhaps like this:

```
create table Drawing (
    DrawingId int not null primary key,
    Name varchar not null
)

create table ShapeKind (
    ShapeKindId int primary key,
    ShapeKindName varchar
)
insert into ShapeKind values (1, 'Line')
insert into ShapeKind values (2, 'Circle')

create table Shape (
    ShapeId int not null,
    ShapeKindId int not null,
    DrawingId int not null,
    CenterX numeric not null,
    CenterY numeric not null,
    SizeX numeric not null,
    SizeY numeric not null,
    Color int not null,
    primary key (ShapeId, ShapeKindId),
    foreign key (ShapeKindId) references ShapeKind (ShapeKindId),
    foreign key (DrawingId) references Drawing (DrawingId)
)

create table Line (
    ShapeId int not null,
    ShapeKindId int not null check (ShapeKindId = 1),
    LineWidth int not null,
    Orientation int not null,
    primary key (ShapeId, ShapeKindId),
    foreign key (ShapeId, ShapeKindId) references Shape (ShapeId, ShapeKindId)
)

create table Circle (
    ShapeId int not null,
    ShapeKindId int not null check (ShapeKindId = 2),
    FillColor int, -- null if not filled
    primary key (ShapeId, ShapeKindId),
    foreign key (ShapeId, ShapeKindId) references Shape (ShapeId, ShapeKindId)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your option of number 2 stands out the most to me.

At the place I work we have a database system that stores meta information about work flows; there is a central table that stores the basic workflow item information (ID, Item Name, Default Person Responsible, etc) and then each type of item has its own table that stores the extra info (Documents have a table with template locations and document types, Processes have a table with their workflow members etc).

It sort of works along the line of inheritance in programming; a base table (the type) and then tables of other types that inherit from the base table.

So you could end up with:

```
shapeland.BaseShape ( ShapeId INT, ShapeType INT, ShapeDescription VARCHAR )
shapeland.Circle (ShapeId INT, Fill BIT, FillColor INT) 
etc etc
```

Or of course if you are a more of a code rather than sql person; you could always store the flattened xml version of a class; although that becomes less readable in the database.

Comment: How is the performance of the system you described? I think it would be a problem when listing a lot of items.

Comment: Ours is used rather intensivly by around 1000 users via a range of web applications and they don't see much in the way of negative performance. It all depends on how you fetch the data. For instance if you needed to fetch all shapes with ids between 1000 and 1500 then write a query for fetching them all at once using a structured parameter (table of ints for example), and return one recordset per sub table. Then parse it in your end program to link the record sets together.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered several question like this recently, the most recent being [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591851/database-structure-design/29646267#29646267).

In short, you have a master or base table (Shapes) that contains the data that is common to all the shapes. It has an auto-generated key value, but also has an indicator of the specific shape (Cirlce, Square, etc.) each row represents.

The sub-tables each contain the shape-specific data. There will be one for Circles, one for Squares/Rectangles, one for Arcs, and so forth.

One obvious enhancement is to have a view for each shape which joins the shape-specific data with the common data. So if the app has the id of a shape with is a Triangle, it queries the Triangles view to get all the data for it. If is has an id value but doesn't know which shape it is, it can query the master table (or call a function) to obtain the kind of shape so it can then query the proper view.

Triggers on the views would allow for new Triangles, Squares, etc. to be created and existing ones to be edited or removed. The app (and app developer) doesn't even need to know the split-table design details. If designed properly, everything can can take place through the views. The app/developers don't even have to know they are views.

Adding a new kind of shape, Octogon say, would be easy: simply create a new Octogons table and view pair. Existing app code would not be affected.