# How to correctly Model a Product to its category SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, data-modeling

I know this seems silly but I'm having a really hard time with this structure.

My data model is for a computer store (strictly academical only), so I have a generate product table for things like, title (*i7 4790*) description, unit price and specifications. Then it links to suppler and Category.

Category will have all the parent Category's  like motherboard, CPU, power supply etc.

But now I'm not sure if I should then go and have a table for each of, referring to the category table, so motherboard would have things like, chip set and socket, CPU could have a chip set as well, and maybe clock speed, power supply could have capacity.

But then I could have a sub category table That referring to itself, but I'm not fully sure how to structure that.

Please could you help me with the right design decision and why it's the best decision, also what are the pros and cons per solution.

***EDIT***

[image]

Here is a quick Model that i wiped up of my thinking so far. The product table will hold the general details of all products, such as *Name* of the product, *Unit price*, *Description* and *Specifications* and they will then link to the catagory table that will then link to the different tables, like motherboard, CPU, Memory etc.

The reason im thinking like this is because each catagory, Motherboard, CPU Case etc, is an entity on its own, an object on its own, so it deserves a table of its specific attributes.

Am i on the right track ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591851/database-structure-design/29646267#29646267) along these lines. You can have a Product table with all the data that is common to all products (SKU, shipping weight, mfg, mfg order num, retail price, etc.) and then, using the Categories value, place category-specific data in separate tables, using the category value to enforce the integrity of the whole system.

Comment: Hi there Tom, sorry im getting back to you so late, Please ready my Edit above, i thank you for your input and seems like im on the right track, please advice

Comment: Better. But one thing that jumps right out. Suppose you have a product ID = 1000 listed in the Products table. According to the CategoryID it is a Motherboard. However, what is to prevent the value 1000 from being entered into the CPU and/or Memory table? Placing Product( ID, CategoryID ) in a unique index and using that as a FK reference from the other tables will prevent that. A Motherboard entry *must* have a CategoryID for "Motherboard", a CPU entry *must* have a CategoryID for "CPU" and so forth. That way, the only table that can have a product ID of 1000 is the Motherboard table.

Comment: What i did was place the Category Id inside the Product table, so for Product Id 1000, it will have the Category id of 1, in the category table, Id 1 will equal Motherboard, Will this not suffice ?

Comment: No, this just designates that product 1000 is a motherboard. Beyond that, there is nothing to prevent an entry into the CPU table of (1000, 2) -- say 2 means CPU. Same problem with Memory table. It should be impossible to define a CPU or Memory with an ID of 1000.
This constraint could be enforced by triggers, but why go to all that trouble and overhead when you can get the system to do at a much lower level? Good rule of thumb: enforce integrity at the lowest possible level that makes sense: domain definition, check constraint, referential constraint, trigger, scheduled tasks, app code.