# I want to remove redundancy in table fields in my database design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework, database-design

I am having 2 tables:

**Student Master**:

> Id,Firstname,Lastname,email,Phone
>   no,Countryid,stateid,cityid,Profilepicurl,gender,Dateofbirth.

**CoachMaster**:

> Id,Firstname,Lastname,email,Phone
>   no,Countryid,stateid,cityid,Profilepicurl,gender,Dateofbirth,Language.

Now you might notice that this 2 tables are having common fields only except 1 extra field i.e **Language** in **coachmaster**.

I am thinking to make a single table which comprises of all fields from both the table i.e this **UserMaster**(contains both StudentMaster and CoachMaster) like this:

**UserMaster**:

> Id,rest all common fields,Language(from Coach Master)

I have discuss this with **one of my friend who is an experienced developer** and what he told me to create seperate table only and he has shown me 2 below 2 scenarios for creating **2 seperate tables**:

1. If i am having 1 common table only that is UserMaster and if in future i want to add 2 extra fields in coach master then this structure would be bad.
2. If i am adding those 2 extra fields needed for coach in UserMaster and if i just want any specific student details then those 2 extra fields(added in my 1st point for coach) will be unneccessarily fetched too.

**Note**:Other Scenarios might exist too with having only 1 table maintaining both coach and student details.

Apart from this what my friend told me that i am not following normalization rule here and if i am having **one single table only that is usermaster** only then for identifying which user is student and **which user is tutor i would always have to use join that is check is** **Userinrole** table which i will maintain like this:

> Role Master:Id,Name(Value:Student,Coach)
>
> UserInRole:RoleId(Reference to RoleMaster Id),UserId(store either
>   Studentid or CoachId)

This is how i would always have to find whether it is coach r student when i would be having any **id**.

So can anybody help guide me regarding how to create a good structure which will solve that 2 scenarios and avoid unneccessary creation of duplicate fields in both this table??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly maintain one table for both Student and Coach, but, as you have noticed yourself, this has maintainability issues. However, there is one flaw in your (or your friend's) analysis. If you have a single table with an indicator showing the user type ('S' or 'C', for example) with a lookup table like this:

```
ID   Name     <other>
==   ====     =======
 S   Student  ...
 C   Coach    ...
```

A FK reference from the indicator field in the Users table to this table would enforce the rule that a user must be one or the other and nothing else. However, queries would not always have to join to this table. The system would verify that the value of the FK exists in that table when you perform an Insert of the Users table or an Update that changed the value of this indicator field. Otherwise, queries would join to this table only if they wanted to get some of the other data stored there.

Having said that, unless you know that your design will be very stable for quite a while, I would suggest a supertable-subtable design. A more detailed answer to a similar question can be found here:

[Designing relationships around an inheritance structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574929/designing-relationships-around-an-inheritance-structure/32597847#32597847)

In your case, the generic or super Masters table would look like your current StudentMaster table with the addition of a MasterType field:

```
create table Masters(
    ID         int not null auto_generated primary key,
    ...
    MasterType char( 1 ) not null,
    ...
    constraint FK_Masters_Type foreign key( MasterType )
        references MasterTypes( ID ),
    constraint UQ_Masters_Type unique( ID, MasterType )
);
```

The FK forces the entry to being defined either as a Student or Coach. Then the StudentMaster table would be simple as it adds no new attributes to the generic master:

```
create table StudentMasters(
    MasterID    int not null primary key,
    MasterType  char( 1 ) check( MasterType = 'S' ),
    constraint  FK_StudentMasters_Master foreign key( MasterID, MasterType )
        references Masters( ID, MasterType )
);
```

The check means that only Students can be inserted into this table. The FK means that the ID must match an entry in the Masters table and it also must be defined as a Student. The ID values in Students that have been defined as Coach (or any possible future type) cannot be stored in the StudentMasters table.

The CoachMasters table would be the same except it would define the Language field and the check would be "MasterType = 'C'".

Now you have options when referencing masters from other tables. For those FKs that refer to a Master, regardless of type, the reference can be defined to the Masters table. If it can only be, say, a Coach (CoachedBy), the reference can be made to the CoachMasters table. Thus, the ID value of a Student can never be accidentally inserted in that field. The same with references that must refer only to Students.

Another suggestion: front these table with two views, CoachMasters and StudentMasters (rename the tables to something else). Then your app can get coach or student information without even knowing about the underlying structure. Triggers on the views will allow all operations to go through the views. This frees you to make changes to the physical layout of the tables should the need arise. Simply redefine the views and triggers and the application code need not change at all. This one trick can increase the maintainability of your database a great deal.

Answer (score 2):

SQL doesn't provide very good support for "one-of" relationships.  There are methods, but they tend to be a bit clunky.

Because you are thinking about "users" in addition to "students" and "coaches", it sounds like you have another entity.  "Users" are either "students" or "coaches".

I think I would approach your problem in one of two ways.

Both start with a `Users` table, with all the fields in students.  This *is* the primary key for users, students, and coaches.  All users are considered students, unless they have evidence of being a coach.  What is this evidence?

One possibility is a `type` column in the `Users` table along with the additional fields needed.  This is often a very reasonable approach to this problem.

The second is an addition table `Coaches` with a primary key of a `CoachId` that is also a foreign key to `UserId`.  This contains the additional information about coaches.  In addition, it makes it easy to set up foreign key relationships where that is needed.

Comment: can you provide any simple structure describing your answer?

Comment: @Learning What is a "simple structure"? (A picture? SQL?) Why is the answer's clear text not enough?