# How to design mysql db where one table should be related to only one of two others?

Tags: database-design, django-models

Let's assume I have books and reviews and I also have comments which can be related to books or reviews, but not to both of them at the same time, how should I design my DB then? I figured I can do it this way, but then comments can be related to both books and reviews...:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Review(models.Model):
    review = models.TextField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(null=True)
    review = models.ForeignKey(null=True)
```

Comment: Answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574929/designing-relationships-around-an-inheritance-structure/32597847#32597847 and other places. You just need to implement a super/sub structure in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) is the official way of doing it, but GenericForeignKey sucks.

> A normal ForeignKey can only “point to” one other model, which means
>   that if the TaggedItem model used a ForeignKey it would have to choose
>   one and only one model to store tags for. The contenttypes application
>   provides a special field type (GenericForeignKey) which works around
>   this and allows the relationship to be with any model:

Well yeah, not according to that description, but it sucks. so your approach isn't a bad idea. You have two different ways of enforcing the constrain. The first is at the database level and will be 100% foolproof, that is to create an ON INSERT TRIGGER that will check that either of the two fields happen to be null.

The second way is to overide the save method in the model.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.book and self.review:
        raise ValueError('Hey you cant do that')
    else:
        Super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```